# How to use if statement in laravel model

Tags: laravel, model, builder

I am using builder in my model and print data in blade,

The issue is my data are stored in database with short-names so I want to write actual names when they print in blade and not just to return those short-names but I can't get if statement to work in my builder.

## code

```
    public function buildFooter($footer, $positionid = 'footer') 
        { 
          $result = null;
          foreach($footer as $item) 
            if($item->type == $positionid) {
              $result .= "<li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-position='{$item->position}' data-id='{$item->id}'>
              <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>
                <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>
              </div>
              <div class='nested-list-content'>

//if part
                if('{$item->widget}' == 'feature-posts')
                    Feature Posts
                elseif('{$item->widget}' == 'feature-posts-sidebar')
                    Feature Posts (Sidebar)
                elseif('{$item->widget}' == 'top-categories-posts')
                    Top Categories (By Posts)
                elseif('{$item->widget}' == 'top-categories-visits')
                    Top Categories (By Visits)
                else
                    Popular Posts
                endif
//if part
                - {$item->status}
                <div class='float-right'>
                  <a href=''>Edit</a> |
                  <a href='#' class='delete_toggle' rel='{$item->id}'>Delete</a>
                </div>
              </div>".$this->buildFooter($footer, $item->id) . "</li>"; 
            }
          return $result ?  "\n<ol class=\"dd-list\">\n$result</ol>\n" : null; 
        }
        // Getter for the HTML menu builder
        public function getHTMLFooter($items)
        {
            return $this->buildFooter($items);
        }
```

## error

```
syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF)
```

Any idea?

## Update

Ok i figured there was issue in my blade that I got error but now that my blade loads I get data like this:

[image: one]

### current code

```
public function buildFooter($footer, $positionid = 'footer') 
    { 
      $result = null;
      foreach($footer as $item) 
        if($item->type == $positionid) {
          $result .= "<li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-position='{$item->position}' data-id='{$item->id}'>
          <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>
          </div>
          <div class='nested-list-content'>
//if part
            if($item->widget == 'feature-posts')
                Feature Posts
            elseif($item->widget == 'feature-posts-sidebar')
                Feature Posts (Sidebar)
            elseif($item->widget == 'top-categories-posts')
                Top Categories (By Posts)
            elseif($item->widget == 'top-categories-visits')
                Top Categories (By Visits)
            else
                Popular Posts
            endif
// if part
            - {$item->status}
            <div class='float-right'>
              <a href=''>Edit</a> |
              <a href='#' class='delete_toggle' rel='{$item->id}'>Delete</a>
            </div>
          </div>".$this->buildFooter($footer, $item->id) . "</li>"; 
        }
      return $result ?  "\n<ol class=\"dd-list\">\n$result</ol>\n" : null; 
    }
    // Getter for the HTML menu builder
    public function getHTMLFooter($items)
    {
        return $this->buildFooter($items);
    }
```

## Update 2

Based on suggestion in comments I've made changes below

*added `".` and `."` around if and some changes in return texts li adding `''` around them.*

```
//code

<div class='nested-list-content'>".
            if ($item->widget == 'feature-posts'){
                'Feature Posts'
            } elseif ($item->widget == 'feature-posts-sidebar') {
                'Feature Posts (Sidebar)'
            } elseif ($item->widget == 'top-categories-posts') {
                'Top Categories (By Posts)'
            } elseif ($item->widget == 'top-categories-visits') {
                'Top Categories (By Visits)'
            } else {
                'Popular Posts'
            }
            - {$item->status}
            ."<div class='float-right'>
//code
```

and now i get

```
syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)
```

On

```
if ($item->widget == 'feature-posts'){
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't use blade templates? In your blade view files, it is much easier to achieve these by @if($conditions) ... @endif.

Comment: yes the reason is i'm using jquery nestabe in this way i just make `{!!$xxxxx!!}` and my nestable form is ready to use

Comment: It seems you are missing a double quote after `<div class='nested-list-content'>`. That's why the statements are printed as is... You should connect the $resutlt in 3 parts (if statement as the middle part).

Comment: I'm getting this now `syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)`

Comment: @JohnDoe any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed some " and ', Kindly try this below,

```
        public function buildFooter($footer, $positionid = 'footer'){
            $result = null;
            foreach($footer as $item)
                if($item->type == $positionid) {
                    $result .= "<li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-position='{$item->position}' data-id='{$item->id}'>";
                    $result .= "<div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'><i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i></div><div class='nested-list-content'>";
                    if ($item->widget == 'feature-posts'){
                         $result .= "Feature Posts";
                    } elseif ($item->widget == 'feature-posts-sidebar') {
                         $result .= "Feature Posts (Sidebar)";
                    } elseif ($item->widget == 'top-categories-posts') {
                         $result .= "Top Categories (By Posts)";
                    } elseif ($item->widget == 'top-categories-visits') {
                         $result .= "Top Categories (By Visits)";
                    } else {
                         $result .= "Popular Posts";
                    }
                    $result .="-".$item->status;
                    $result .="<div class='float-right'><a href='#' class='delete_toggle text-danger' rel='{$item->id}'>Delete</a></div></div>".$this->buildFooter($footer, $item->id) . "</li>";
                  }
             return $result ?  "\n<ol class=\"dd-list\">\n$result</ol>\n" : null;
        }
```

Comment: I checked there is no `{` open.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

I am sure there are other ways to achieve this. Your approach is mixing up views and controller actions.

```
<?php 

public function buildFooter($footer, $positionid = 'footer') 
    { 
      $result = null;
      foreach($footer as $item) 
        if($item->type == $positionid) {
          $result .= "
          <li class='dd-item nested-list-item' data-position='"
          . $item->position
          ."' data-id='".$item->id."'>
          <div class='dd-handle nested-list-handle'>
            <i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i>
          </div>
          <div class='nested-list-content'>";
//if part
            if($item->widget == 'feature-posts'):
                $result .= "Feature Posts";
            elseif($item->widget == 'feature-posts-sidebar'):
                $result .= "Feature Posts (Sidebar)";
            elseif($item->widget == 'top-categories-posts'):
                $result .= "Top Categories (By Posts)";
            elseif($item->widget == 'top-categories-visits'):
                $result .= "Top Categories (By Visits)";
            else:
                $result .= "Popular Posts";
            endif;
// if part
        $result .= "- " . $item->status
            ."<div class='float-right'>
              <a href=''>Edit</a> |
              <a href='#' class='delete_toggle' rel='{$item->id}'>Delete</a>
            </div>
          </div>".$this->buildFooter($footer, $item->id) . "</li>"; 
        }
      return $result ?  "\n<ol class=\"dd-list\">\n".$result."</ol>\n" : null; 
    }

// Getter for the HTML menu builder
public function getHTMLFooter($items)
{
    return $this->buildFooter($items);
}
```

Comment: it works in this condition `$result .= "- " .  $item->status `

Comment: Updated. Please check.. I recommend you read through the Laravel documentation on Blade template and Controllers...